# Z[x,.y,.....] generated by 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand an example in my book,

let R = Z[x,y,.....] be a polynomial ring on infinitely many indeterminates.
Then R is finitely generated as an R-module, with generator 1.

I don't understand how this can be.

Comment: Every unital ring is a (left) module over itself generated by $1$, for if $r\in R$, we can write $r\cdot 1=r$.

Comment: ok thanks, think i get it. Thought i needed something to generate the polynomials as well.

Comment: I think you were confused between generation of $R$ over $R$ and generation of $R$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. It is true that $R$ is not finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ya this is what confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every ring with unit $R$ is finitely generated as $R$-module by $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$, because for every $r \in R$ we have $$r = r \cdot 1 $$